# Google Sheets - cumulative sum multiple sub tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I am currently trying to get the cumulative sum of a column of values. The data looks something along the lines of:

[image: fig1]

This can be achieved by fixing the range at `2` and sum up the columns from `A$2`. For instance the formula for B7 would be `=SUM(A$2:A7)`.

However, this is not ideal if I stack up multiple instances of the same table. For instance:

[image: fig2]

In the second instance, I would like the start to be at `A9` instead of `A2`. Is there a way I can make it start from `A9` instead?

The goal for me is to have a sheet with many instances of this small table stacked together, but obviously the fixed `A2` would be a problem for this. Any pointers on how to achieve this would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest making everything relative. One way is by using the following scheme:

1. in **b2** enter `=A2`
2. in **b3** enter `=A3+B2`
3. copy the formula in b3 which is relative to **b4:b7**

If you decide to replicate the table all formulas are now relative.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks for the easy solution! I totally dug myself into a hole.